# XMLHttpRequest cannot load.... Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to print a json that this broker on my server, but i can not return the json, the chorme me of the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest can not load .... Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

can someone help me?

the following code:`

```
console.log("carregando..");
var username = "admin";
var password = "password";
$.ajax({

   type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhots/api/json/broker/dest-metrics',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers : {Accept : "application/json","Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"},
    beforeSend : function(req) {
                                    req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic " +Base64.encode(username+":"+password))
                                    console.log("Autenticado!!");
    },
    success: function(data) { console.log("Sucesso!!"); },
    error: function (data) {
              console.log("ERRO");
         },
    data: {},
   async: false,
   cache: false,
   jsonp: true 



});`
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `localhots` not `localhost` ?

Comment: in my code that the number ip, not localhost, did not let me put the ip number in question;)

Comment: Most likely you are getting blocked by the same-origin policy, and aren't taking the proper steps to make a proper CORS request. Did you instead intend to make a JSONP request? `jsonp: true` doesn't make sense for a CORS Request, and `headers : {Accept : "application/json","Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"},` doesn't make sense for a jsonp request.

Comment: I've been researching the CORS plus how do I set up my code, or I have to configure my server?

Comment: when I make a request with JSONP including callback, the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: Well, for both CORS and JSONP, the server you are requesting from has to support it. Do you have access to that server to make it support JSONP or CORS?

Comment: I have access, but my boss does not allow to modify any configuration server;/

Comment: have any idea how to configure the server to support? the server and apache, thanks

Comment: got, had to disable security with chrome by typing the following command in the terminal: google-chrome - disable-web-security
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this problem is that the uri of the page is file :/ /, this problem disappears if the execution is done from a server, but another option is to start Chrome with
 `- allow-file-access-from-files`

Comment: If you are under windows open command console and type `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`... In other case you have to ask the way.

Comment: got, had to disable security with chrome by typing the following command in the terminal: google-chrome - disable-web-security
thank you